# Component prop doesn't update DOM on nested object changes

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a multidimensional object which looks like this:

```
obj: {
   1: {
     'a' => [ [] ],
     'b' => [ [] ]
   },
   2: {
     'x' => [ [], [] ]
   }
}
```

I have it in my root. I also have a watch for this object, and I am updating another object accordingly...

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     obj: {},
     newObj: {}
  },

  watch: {
    obj: {
      handler(obj) {

     }
    }
  }
})
```

I am using newObj as a prop and pass it to a component to perform for loops.

Inside handler, if I use make a change in first level key of object, the component updates the dom the DOM.

```
 handler(obj) {
    this.$set(this.newObj, key, {
       [innerKey]: [ [] ]
    });
 }
```

However if I try changing the secondary-level keys, the component doesn't update the DOM.

```
 handler(obj) {
    var key = 1;
    var additions = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    // First try:
    var scafold = this.newObj[key]
    scafold[additions[i]] = [ [] ];
    this.newObj[key] = scafold;

    // Second try:
    this.$set(this.newObj[key], additions[i], [ [] ]);
 }
```

Although, if I check vue debugger, it shows the object is updated as wanted using both ways, the DOM doesn't change.

As I said, I believe it is that it doesn't watch inner keys and respond to it. What is the proper way of overcoming this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `this.$forceUpdate();` after `this.$set`?

Comment: I didn't. but I found the solution just now. First I do `delete this.newObj[key]` and then `this.$set(this.transferForms, key, scalfold)` and it worked

Comment: I would advise against using ```delete this.newObj[key]``` since it creates a know performance degradation. ```this.$forceUpdate()``` was specifically created to address your problem, might as well try it out.

Comment: I tried this.$forceUpdate here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9nmxn9/15/ , but I couldn't make it work for the component-case

Comment: Your component is not correctly defined, props is a map, so should look like

```{
   props: {
       newObj: Array
   }
}
```